# Оптимизация кода C#

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Имеется код C# Он полностью выполняет свои требования но проблема в том что dataGridView сильно тормозит

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) return;
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var s = Regex.CacheSize;
    now = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 0, 0, 0);
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Срок до"].Value != null &&
        ((DateTime)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Срок до"].Value).CompareTo(now) < 0)
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

    for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            var formattedValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].FormattedValue;
            if (formattedValue != null && formattedValue.ToString().ToLower() == "удален")
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }

   for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
       for (var j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
       {
           var formattedValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].FormattedValue;
           if (formattedValue != null && formattedValue.ToString().ToLower() == "неограничен")
           {
               dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
           }
       }

}
```

прошу помощи с оптимизацией так как пока не силён в этом деле

Comment: Зачем вы идете циклом по всем строкам, если вам надо определиться лишь с цветом одной строки?

Comment: @PavelMayorov нет не одной строки. Он грузит из базы в dataGridView и должен подсветить если срок истекший красным, но когда добавляют  комментарии он меняет цвет

Comment: Вы же дважды проходите `GridView`(`for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)`) зачем, достаточно одного

Comment: @Bald да. Ну я буду очень признателен если Вы мне поможете сделать лучше.

Comment: Посмотрит текущий вариант ответа, убрал построчный обход грида, в связи с тем что ваш код отрабатывает при перерисовки строки индекст текущей строки можно получить из `e.RowIndex`, т.е. достаточно обхода по колонкам

Answer (score 12, accepted):

я бы попробовал для начала переписать так:

```
var currentRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
for (var j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    var formattedValue = dataGridView1.Rows[currentRowIndex].Cells[j].FormattedValue;
    var stringValue = formattedValue.ToString().ToLower().Trim();
    switch(stringValue)
    {
        case "удален":
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[currentRowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            break;
        }
        case "неограничен":
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[currentRowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            //действие по умолчанию
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

можно использовать и условный оператор `if` но мне больше *нравится* `switch`

Comment: @Bald огромное тебе человеческое спасибо. Вообще по другому ПО стало работать, дай бог тебе здоровье!

Comment: @Павел не за что, мой первоначальный ответ работал бы быстрее изначального но с корректировкой от PavelMayorov стало я думаю еще лучше

Answer (score 5):

Какую технологию вы используете? Если WinForms, то DataGridView сам по себе очень долго отрисовывается. Для обхода этой проблемы нужно создать свой контрол, унаследованный от DataGridView, и задать в нем оптимизацию буфера.

```
public class ucGridControl : DataGridView
{
    public ucGridControl ( )
        : base ( )
    {
        SetStyle ( ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true );
    }
}
```

Соответственно в форме создавайте уже экземпляр своего класса.

Comment: А можно поподробней?

Comment: Всё разобрался. Класс спасибо тебе большое. Это просто космос))))

Comment: а разве нельзя использовать предложенную Вами оптимизацию без создания *прослойки* в виде *отнаследованного* от базового контрола?

Comment: У данного метода определён модификатор доступа protected, мне не удалось найти какой-либо публичный метод для установки этих параметров.